# Trimming in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How would i go about trimming this field '633827-9062-5000-0006 4'
to look like 633827906250000006.
Using trim functions?

The field will always be the same length & i need to remove the last character.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The two trim functions `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` are only for removing white space from the beginning and end of a string. You cannot remove other characters. You should use `REPLACE` to remove the characters you do not want, and then use `RTRIM` to remove the white space from the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `replace` to remove the dashes and then `left` to get the 18 first chars.

```
left(replace(your_string, '-',''), 18)
```

In your example this would remove the white space and the 4 at the end and retain the first 18 characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @value varchar(50) = '633827-9062-5000-0006 4';
SELECT REPLACE(RTRIM(LEFT(@value, LEN(@value) - 1)), '-', '')
```

Comment: Why the `rtrim`? It seems unnecessary as the length is known in advance.

Comment: There's no mention that second last character will be always a 'space' so my assumption is that it could be any character.

Comment: Fair enough. I didn't think of that case.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the last 2 characters (space and '4'), you could use SUBSTRING and REPLACE as in the following examples:

```
declare @s varchar(50);
declare @t varchar(50);
set @s = '633827-9062-5000-0006 4';

set @t = substring(@s, 1, 21)
print '[' + @t + ']';

set @t = substring(@s, 1, len(@s) - 2);
print '[' + @t + ']';

set @t = replace(substring(@s, 1, len(@s) - 2), '-', '');
print '[' + @t + ']';
```

In the first PRINT statement, I am hard-coding the length, and in the second, I calculate the final string length.  If you wanted to remove the dashes as well, the third assignment does this as well.

If the string length could ever be less than 2 characters, STRING will complain about 'Invalid length parameter passed to the substring function.'  You could use a CASE statement to protect against that.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @s varchar(50);
set @s = '633827-9062-5000-0006 4';
select replace(substring(@s,0,charindex(' ',@s)),'-','')
```